# Graphing two observations, not variables

Tags: stata

The data looks like

```
year 1970 1971 1972
 num    3   1     4
```

But "graph twoway line year num" does not work here because they are not variable names.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transpose your data to do almost anything interesting or useful. You don't say what your variable names are, but here is some technique.

```
clear 
input str4 whatever x y z 
year 1970 1971 1972
 num    3   1     4
end 

xpose, clear 
drop in 1 
rename (v?) (year num)
```

The names in your string variable won't get past the `xpose` but for your example it is trivial to `rename` what you get.